# Android fade out animation using Cosine function

Tags: android, android-animation, trigonometry

I in my Android Honeycomb application there is a View which has a fade in and fade out animation. Here's most part of the animation code:

```
 <scale
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:duration="500" />
```

The way it's working right now the animation happens in a linear time but I want to do it according the Cosine function, that is from Cos(0) until Cos(0,5*pi) the fade out case. 
Is it possible to do such thing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are free to create your own `Interpolator`. ([See the interface description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html).) This can then be applied with `Animation.setInterpolator(Interpolator)`. Or, see [this discussion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Interpolators) for ways of applying custom `Interpolators` in XML.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want linear interpolation, you have choice between:

> AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator, AccelerateInterpolator,
>   AnticipateInterpolator, AnticipateOvershootInterpolator,
>   BounceInterpolator, CycleInterpolator, DecelerateInterpolator,
>   LinearInterpolator, OvershootInterpolator

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html

So maybe what is the closest to a Cosine is:

> AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator
>
> An interpolator where the rate of change starts and ends slowly but
>   accelerates through the middle.